# How to find duplicate cell and remove entire row in a CSV with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv with data that pretty much looks like this:

```
john, 10002
max, 10003
lucy, 10004
steve, 10005
dave, 10005
sara, 10004
```

I want to remove any rows that have a duplicate 2nd cell(the cell with the numbers in it)
so for example, the data above would turn just into:

```
   john, 10002
    max, 10003
```

I have research finding and removing duplicates but all of the examples I have found have only removed the duplicate cell, or only looked for rows that are a complete duplicate of another row rather than just a duplicate in one cell. Does anyone have any idea on how I could do this?

Comment: Use `pandas` library

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas` library and use `drop_duplicates` with `keep=False`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('a.csv') # Your File name

df.drop_duplicates('id', keep=False)
df.to_csv('dedup.csv', index=False)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   name     id
0  john  10002
1   max  10003
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there any way to have it preform the opposite opperation? So in this case it would only remove rows that weren't duplicates?